# ajaxform with yii cannot find data , give me an error

Tags: php, ajax, database, yii

I want to do an edit of some data via a pop edit window with save and delete. It worked previously with other data ( means other table) just fine. 
Now I am followiing problem.

This table has two primary keys. One is 'id' and other one is 'text'.

```
public function actionAjaxEditForm($id) {

    $data = products::model()->findbyPk($id);


    echo CJSON::encode(array('data' => $data));

    Yii::app()->end();}
```

**the error ist a 500 internal error**

I tried with

```
findbyPk(array($id => 'id', $text = 'text'));
```

I thought I will link the 2 primary keys..but I think the problem lies somewhere else..and I dont know where. Thanks!

update :

with

```
find(array($id = 'id'));
```

gives me different  error:
**CExeption**:

**Attribute CDbCriteria.0 is not defined**

Comment: `find(array($id = 'id'));` this is wrong. The array you passing is not correct and this should be `array( 'id' => $id)`

Comment: Ok I tried that but I got another error. Attribute CDbCriteria.id is not defined.